# Firefox eliminates a zero at prefix for the input type=number

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

In firefox for `input type=number` it automatically eliminates the zero at the prefix. Consider the decimal which contain something like `.08`, but it shows only `.8` ( Currently we have two different input type number fields, one for `currency` and other for `decimal`) whereas it is required to show `$100.00` but it shows only `$100.0` ie., it doesn't checks whether it is amount (or) decimal. It checks only the value.

Let me know whether is an fixable or default behavior of firefox

```html
<input type="number" value="100">.<input type="number" value="08">
```

Comment: I have just tested an `<input type="number" step="0.01" />` in firefox, and it works as it should be. I am getting `3.02` (the number I input) in the request. Make sure you are doing everything correctly

Comment: It does? Not in mine :-? [(fiddle)](http://jsbin.com/qurovaluqe/1/edit?html,output).

Comment: Thanks @Ivanov, It is working fine if have have single input box. But am currently using two input box for showing currency and the decimal respectively.

Comment: Please edit the question and show your code. Stack Overflow even allows to embed a runnable snippet. As said, it isn't as simple as Firefox number fields being broken.

Comment: Added @Álvaro González, I need `08` in the input type number box in firefox.!

Comment: I've created the snippet for you. But the code doesn't match your problem description anyway.

Comment: Are you by chance trying to split a single decimal number into two different inputs?

Comment: Updated the snippet

Comment: Is there any compelling reason to split this into two parts?  As a user, I'd rather enter a single number.  Then you can use `step` (and in either case, I'd suggest using `min` and `max` as well).  See also [Mozilla Guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general terms, if you have any given data type, you can't split data and keep its integrity:

- `2018-01-16T10:22:40.315Z` is a date/time; `10` or `T` are not.
- `webmaster@example.com` is an email; `webmaster`, `@`  and `example.com` are not.

If you decide to split a decimal number like `100.08` into `100`, `.` and `08` you no longer have a decimal. You can still consider the `100` part as an integer number but `08` is at most an alphanumeric string because the leading zero is significant.

Is there a way to change the output format? Certainly, not if you stick to standards. The [HTML Living Standard by WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type%3Dnumber)) says:

> This specification does not define what user interface user agents are
>   to use; user agent vendors are encouraged to consider what would best
>   serve their users' needs. For example, a user agent in Persian or
>   Arabic markets might support Persian and Arabic numeric input
>   (converting it to the format required for submission as described
>   above). Similarly, a user agent designed for Romans might display the
>   value in Roman numerals rather than in decimal; or (more
>   realistically) a user agent designed for the French market might
>   display the value with apostrophes between thousands and commas before
>   the decimals, and allow the user to enter a value in that manner,
>   internally converting it to the submission format described above.

Whatever workaround you use, it must be developed in a per-browser basis and using non-standard extensions (if any). It honestly feels much more work than just writing a custom JavaScript-based control from scratch.

Your approach can be correct but you cannot use the standard-based browser builtin tools for it.

Comment: Agreed. But it cant be changed? Because Chrome can able to show `08` but firefox cant.!

Comment: I've added a quote from Living Standard that explicitly states that formatting is out of the scope of the HTML5 spec.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to prevent this problem with  number input :

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" ...
```

Will bring up the numeric keypad on iPhone and the nicer Android phones and all 0 will be accepted.